# jQuery DataTables and IE/Chrome/Safari: table overlaps footer instead of pushing it down

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, datatables

This only happens on Google Chrome and Safari (not a problem on Firefox).

If I have  table that with multi-line data, it ends up expanding the table's height -- then instead of pushing down the DIV containing my footer, the table actually overlaps the footer. On Firefox the footer is pushed down as I'd expect.

Can anyone give me suggestion how to resolve this?
Will be glad to include specific code -- the overall structure is as follows:

```
<div>
    <div id="main">

        //datatables being built here

    </div>
    <div id="footer">

        //footer code here

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have some code to show us?

It might be as simple as:

```
#main {
float: left;
clear: both;
}

or 

#main table {
float: left;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: thanks @wes - a simple `float:left` did the trick when applied to `.dataTables_wrapper`